# Некорректный вывод таблицы

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Мне нужно на фрагменте вывести таблицу с пятью полями. И потом этот фрагмент добавить в активити.

Что делаю:

1. Создал фрагмент

   fragment_detect_list.xml

   ```xml
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:name="com.mycompany.DetectFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
       app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
       tools:context=".DetectFragment"
       tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_detect" />
   ```
2. Определил формат строки

   fragment_detect.xml

   ```xml
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/mnc"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
           android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/level_dbm"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
           android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/freq_mhz"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
           android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/cellid"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
           android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/lac"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
           android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Реализовал адаптер

   ```java
   public class DetectFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetectFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter1.ViewHolder> {
       @NonNull
       @Override
       public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           return new ViewHolder(
               FragmentDetectBinding.inflate(
                   LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                   parent,
                   false
               ));
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           // Содержимое ячеек выводим в формате R:{row_num}, C:{col_num}
           holder.mItem = new PlaceholderItem(
               String.format("R:%d, C:%d", position, 1),
               String.format("R:%d, C:%d", position, 2),
               String.format("R:%d, C:%d", position, 3),
               String.format("R:%d, C:%d", position, 4),
               String.format("R:%d, C:%d", position, 5)
           );
           holder.mMncView.setText(holder.mItem.mnc);
           holder.mLevelView.setText(holder.mItem.levelDbm);
           holder.mFreqView.setText(holder.mItem.freqMHz);
           holder.mCellIDView.setText(holder.mItem.cellID);
           holder.mLacView.setText(holder.mItem.lac);
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return 3;  // Будет только три строки
       }

       public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
           public final TextView mMncView;
           public final TextView mLevelView;
           public final TextView mFreqView;
           public final TextView mCellIDView;
           public final TextView mLacView;
           public PlaceholderItem mItem;

           public ViewHolder(FragmentDetectBinding binding) {
               super(binding.getRoot());
               mMncView = binding.mnc;
               mLevelView = binding.levelDbm;
               mFreqView = binding.freqMhz;
               mCellIDView = binding.cellid;
               mLacView = binding.lac;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. И сам класс фрагмента

   ```java
   public class DetectFragment extends Fragment {
       public DetectFragment() {}

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detect_list, container, false);

           // Set the adapter
           if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
               Context context = view.getContext();
               RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
               recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 5)); // 5 колонок
               recyclerView.setAdapter(new DetectFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter1());
           }
           return view;
       }
   }
   ```

Запускаю и вижу такую картину

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. в ряд выводится содержимое ячеек первого столбца.

Вопрос: что я делаю не так?

**Update** следуя совету переписал `onBindViewHolder` и `getItemCount` в такой вид

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position / COL_COUNT);
    switch (position % COL_COUNT) {
        case 0:
            holder.mMncView.setText(holder.mItem.mnc);
            break;
        case 1:
            holder.mLevelView.setText(holder.mItem.levelDbm);
            break;
        case 2:
            holder.mFreqView.setText(holder.mItem.freqMHz);
            break;
        case 3:
            holder.mCellIDView.setText(holder.mItem.cellID);
            break;
        case 4:
            holder.mLacView.setText(holder.mItem.lac);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size() * COL_COUNT;
}
```

Теперь вывод происходит построчно, но только первых двух колонок.

Comment: GridLayoutManager наполняет список не по колонкам, а по строкам. При этом для каждой ячейки получаете `row = position / 5; col = position % 5;` и выводите содержимое ячейки. Соответственно itemCount->15. Будет три строки и 5 колонок.

Comment: @YuraIvanov обновил вопрос. Стало лучше, но не до конца

Comment: У вас колонки (они же `TextView`) все пять в разметке одной ячейки. Либо нужно использовать для каждой ячейки один `TextView`, либо вернуть первоначальный вариант и заменить `GridLayoutManager` на вертикальный `LinearLayoutManager`.

Comment: @woesss сейчас пришел к такому же выводу. Уставил один TextView и все заработало